# How do I convert my SVN repository to Git while preserving branches?

Tags: svn, git

Some help please. This doesn't seem to do it for me:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=../authors.txt file:///home/path
```

Comment: Are any branches created in the git repository? (`git branch -a`), what is the layout of the SVN project you are cloning?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use [svn2git](http://github.com/jcoglan/svn2git), a ruby script that handles all of that for you. I've used it over the past 8 months or so to convert several quite large subversion repos to git; it's by far the best tool I've found for the job.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty thorough set of instructions available [here](http://progit.org/book/ch8-2.html), including how to convert SVN "tags" and "branches" into actual Git tags and branches.

Answer (score 0):

I have had great luck with specifying the branches and tags explicitly:

```
git svn clone http://server.com/svn/project -T trunk -b branches -t tags project
git remote add origin git@server.com:project
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to clone your SVN with [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/index.html): it translates such SVN concepts like branches, tags, ignores, EOLs to the corresponding Git concepts.

Maybe I will find an easy Howto....